# mysql died with stack trace

Tags: mysql, linux, percona, unix

My mysql server died while running select queries.

Status of every table is good. When I went to the error log I found this:

```
Thread pointer: 0x2ab63e0f49e0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 40f34098 thread_stack 0x40000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x7d08b5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x4b4)[0x6a90e4]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x2b4d4c6a6be0]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x904618]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x904725]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x90496c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x848b18]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x848b7d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x84e581]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x834878]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x82a885]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7fb138]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x7f3b39]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5c38c5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10sub_selectP4JOINP13st_join_tableb+0x66)[0x5bd396]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5c20d7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_ZN4JOIN4execEv+0xca0)[0x5d7570]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z12mysql_selectP3THDPPP4ItemP10TABLE_LISTjR4ListIS1_ES2_jP8st_orderSB_S2_SB_yP13select_resultP18st_select_lex_unitP13st_select_lex+0x12c)[0x5d8d7c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z13handle_selectP3THDP3LEXP13select_resultm+0x1cd)[0x5d982d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x591282]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z21mysql_execute_commandP3THD+0x34b0)[0x599580]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysql_parseP3THDPcjP12Parser_state+0x33b)[0x59b88b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x59c8a2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z16dispatch_command19enum_server_commandP3THDPcj+0x1af2)[0x59ea62]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z10do_commandP3THD+0x167)[0x59f057]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24do_handle_one_connectionP3THD+0x14f)[0x63af3f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_one_connection+0x51)[0x63b121]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x2b4d4c69e77d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x2b4d4d9ef9ad]
```

This is a percona xtradb cluster; version is mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1.

Comment: You need to give the version of MySQL and the request which triggers that. You should ugrade your MySQL to a recent version (or consider MariaDB).

Comment: Not quite enough information. Please post more of the error log both before and after the stack trace.